# What is the meaning is this code block [=,&i]()mutable {}()?

Tags: c++, lambda

I was taking a c++ test and there was a strange code block below which I didn't understand. Here, `i` is an `int` and `code` is a `char`:

```
[=,&i]()mutable
{
  i++;
  code = 'b';
  std::cout << "i:" <<i<<"""code:"<<code <<cout::endl;
}();
```

I don't know how to interpret this; it doesn't look like a typical C++ code block. I've searched online for information about this but can't find anything else on this sort of code style.

What does this code mean?

Comment: It's an _atypic_ lambda definition including the `mutable` keyword. Can you please give us a bit more of the context.

Comment: Read about [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've cleaned up your question a bit to make it easier to read.

Comment: What test was this? Could you provide a link?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Thats all got I am afraid.

Comment: @templatetypedef Thank you for your kindness! Good opening experience I just had through this post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This is a [lambda function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)**, a feature added to the language in 2011.

- The `=` means that copies of variables from the outside are available inside.
- The `&i` means that, despite the above, `i` in particular is actually available by reference.
- The `mutable` keyword allows the `code` copy to be modified inside the function body.
- The trailing `()` "runs" the function immediately after it's declared.

As written, I can't see any particular reason to use a lambda for this. It looks like someone has succeeded at their goal: to confuse you.

Comment: I agree that this code looks needlessly complicated. OP - if you're concerned about whether you should be able to understand what you're looking at, don't be - that sort of code rarely arises in actual C++ code.

Comment: Well, I have 5 years of commercial C++ programming behind my back' thought I knew all the is about lambdas, but never seen `mutable` in this context. Live and learn!

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: I learnt about `mutable` lambdas today too, thanks to you :) I didn't know the keyword were required in this context. Then again, I don't actually do any C++11 development outside of SO, so...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thank you Sir. Have you ever used it in commercial C++ development - presumably surely you have? I have only used Lambda in C# as I mentioned Curious for creating a job task in a seperate thread for excel-dna.

Comment: @templatetypedef Got you. But better to know this in case this appears in a job interview. thanks

Comment: @lzrobbytan: No, at work we are stuck on C++03. Although, as it happens, just today I began putting together a migration plan so we can update our tools.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to explain this bit by bit since the code as is can be confusing, [the expression is a lambda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293608.aspx), I will not talk much about it but you can think of it as a functor defined inline.  Try and run the following code to start,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto function_object = []() {
        cout << "This is a lambda" << endl;
    };
    function_object(); // This will print the above

    return 0;
}
```

The lambda in your question has member variables `i` by reference and everything else referenced in the function body in the lambda is taken from the outside scope by value.  That is what the `[=, &i]` means.

The `()` following that is a regular function arguments expression, similar to the parentheses in the following

```
void function() {};
```

So you could change the lambda to something like this

```
[](int a) {...}(12);
```

And this would call the lambda with the argument `12`.

The part in the braces is the function body as usual.  After the curly brace closes, the lambda is created.  So you can consider everything including and before the curly brace as part of the constructor of the lambda.  Then the last pair of parentheses simply calls the lambda like any other function.

Another thing that I didn't mention is the `mutable` keyword.  Lambdas are by default assumed to not be able to change the values of their member variables.  You need to add the mutable to the lambda to convey to the compiler that it will be modifying its member variables.

You probably need to read up on lambdas elsewhere though.

Some references 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda
http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html

I read the second link when I was trying to understand lambdas initially, but now I go to cppreference every time I have a doubt about the syntax for lambdas!

Try to compile and run the following piece of code.  These are a few examples that might help you understand the code better.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    []() {
        cout << "This is a lambda :)" << endl;
    }();

    auto func = []() {
        cout << "This is another lambda that is stored as a functor in a variable" << endl;
    };
    func();

    int a{10};
    [=]() mutable {
        cout << "I have captured the value of a from the surrounding scope by value " << a << endl;
        a = 20;
    }();

    [&a]() { // notice mutable is not here
        cout << "Here a is captured by reference " << a << endl;
        a = 100;
    }();
    cout << a << endl; // outputs 100

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Curious. I have also tried all your code for enhancing my understanding. They are very helpful. I hope I will come across in the a case of using it in C++ in the future. I only have used lambda expression in C#...

Answer (score 0):

It's a lambda function capturing everything by copy (the `=` bit) and explicitly the `i` variable by reference (the `&i` bit) and the lambda is then being valled straight after declaring it.

If this does not look like typical C++ to you then you are a few years behind the game since this is perfectly fine C++11/14 (and later) code.

Comment: "Perfectly normal"? I would firmly reject this at code review, as currently written.

Comment: Maybe I should have said "the syntax is perfectly fine". I'm guessing that OP is only familliar with C++98 and that's why it looks strange. I was not trying to comment on the quality of the code itself - just saying there is nothing unusual about the syntax - C++11 is 5 years old by now and should be common knowlege at this point (IMHO).

Comment: I estimate ~30 years before it's even vaguely commonplace amongst educational institutions worldwide. Recall that Indian schools still teach a primordial dialect of C++ from 1989 (on emulated DOS!) ... that predates actual standardised C++ by almost a decade!

Comment: That's just insane if true (which I'm not saying it isn't).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I can vouch for that being completely true.  I used Turbo C++ and I graduated high school 3 years ago